# Passing a variable from jQuery within a HTML file to a php file using session through ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to pass a variable from jQuery to a PHP file and I am having a difficulty in doing it.

Here is a simple HTML file of "send.html".

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'receive.php',
        data: {message : "Hello World!"}
      })
      .done(function(data) {
          alert(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have a PHP file of "receive.php".

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];
    echo $_SESSION['message'].'<br />';
  } else {
    echo "message not set";
  }
?>
```

When I click the button on send.html, I get the correct alert saying "Hello World!". But when I access "receive.php" by typing the URL on my webbrowser, I get the message saying:

```
message not set
```

If I want to get "Hello World!" from receive.php, what should I do?
Anybody has a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: that is because you are checking if(isset($_POST['message'])){ and not if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ for direct view you should check for session. There is no POST when you are viewing receive.php directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your receive.php should be

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];
    echo $_SESSION['message'].'<br />';
  }else if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
     echo $_SESSION['message'].'<br />';
  }else{
     echo "message not set";
  }
?>
```